# Change filename of generated Cordova appxupload packages

Tags: cordova, uwp, cordova-win10

I am using Cordova to generate appxupload packages for a Windows UWP app.
Cordova generates the following filename currently:

```
CordovaApp.Windows10_1.5.1.0_x86_x64_bundle.appxupload
```

Is there any way to replace the "CordovaApp"-part with a custom name, e.g. by defining something in the config.xml?

As I am generating multiple variants of the same app (using different config.xml files), I would prefer something like this, as currently the packages are overwritten on each build:

```
MyAppVariant.Windows10_1.5.1.0_x86_x64_bundle.appxupload
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change filename of generated Cordova appxupload packages `CordovaApp.Windows10_1.5.1.0_x86_x64_bundle.appxupload`

This name comes from your `Config.xml` file in your project, you could browse the file and search `packageName` markup. And the default value is  `Cordova.Example` 
Package name for Windows. For custom package name you could modify it. For more please refer this [document](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this has no effect on the file name. Probably it is not possible to change it.

Comment: Could you find the Config.xml file in the UWP client project?